# NivoSlider 3.1 - including keyboardNav

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I'm using WordPress and a plugin called 'jj-ngg-jquery-slider' which makes use of nivo-slider. By default this plugin comes with Nivo Slider 2.6 but I've upgraded the script to its latest version, 3.1. Then I realized that the `keyboardNav` support was removed from this version. Now I'm trying to include the `keyboardNav` back into the script but I don't understand why it's not working.

This is the code for `keyboardNav`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });

    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) 
    { // left
     $(".nivo-prevNav").click();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 39) 
    { // right
        $(".nivo-nextNav").click(); 
    }
    });
</script>
```

I've put this script at the end of the nivo-slider script file, then in `header.php`, then in `footer.php`, then in a separate custom.js file that was imported in header.php. Nothing worked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({keyboardNav: true});
    });
</script>
```

Hope, it will helps you. !!